# C# Define begin of day of a date in another timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, utc

I want to define the begin of a day in another timezone with .NET/C#.

Example: 
  My current timezone = GMT+1 
  so DateTime.Today returns 19/11/2009 23:00 UTC

but actually I want to get the DateTime.Today for timezone GMT+2 which would be 19/11/2009 22:00 UTC.

How do I do this without juggling with offsets & daylightsaving calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().First(tz => tz.StandardName == DesiredTimeZoneName);
Debug.WriteLine(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Ticks, zone.BaseUtcOffset).ToUniversalTime());
```

AFAIK, there's no other way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx). This is new in .NET 3.5.